# Why does the error in matplotlib 3D return as cm not defined

Tags: python

My code is basically this, i am trying to plot and visualise the linear regression between mpg, displacement and horsepower in a 3D graph using matplotlib

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,15))

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_trisurf(auto['mpg'],auto['displacement'],auto['horsepower'], cmap = cm.jet)
```

the error returns as:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-208-0a4e9c165dee> in <module>
      1 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,15))
      2 ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
----> 3 ax.plot_trisurf(auto['mpg'],auto['displacement'],auto['horsepower'], cmap = cm.jet)

NameError: name 'cm' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you import `cm`? `from matplotlib import cm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the `cm.jet` to `'jet'` it will probably work and use the 'jet' colormap of matplotlib (you can see all the different colormaps [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html))

What you are trying to do is to use the library matplotlib.cm however to use that you first need to import the library via `import matplotlib.cm as cm`

This way you use the _jet_data variable defined in cm, however this is quite cumbersome.
I always just use the string reference to the colormap, because then there is no need to import the cm file, so I recommend you to do the same!